# Error "'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'"

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

Recently, I started to work on stock prices analyses in order to optimise my portfolio. I started with an Excel file and several VBA macros. It works quite well but is very slow. So, I'm now trying to step up and set up a proper "stock prices" database on my server ([based on this post](https://reasonabledeviations.com/2018/02/01/stock-price-database/)).

In the "stock_prices" database, there is a "daily_price" table that stores the daily stock prices for some tickers. In order to update the "daily price" table, a python script will be launched every day and it includes the below Python / SQL statements.

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start_date)
for row in df.itertuples():
    values = [YAHOO_VENDOR_ID, ticker_index[ticker]] + list(row)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO daily_price (data_vendor_id, ticker_id, price_date, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, adj_close_price, volume) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", tuple(values))
```

Unfortunately, the "cursor.execute..." line returns the below error :
"AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'"

The print out of the "values" tuple is :
[1, 2, Timestamp('2004-08-19 00:00:00'), 49.81328582763672, 51.83570861816406, 47.80083084106445, 49.9826545715332, 49.9826545715332, 44871300]

Based on what I could read in another similar post, I checked the type of the date index to make sure that it is not an object :

```
Print(df.index.dtype)
```

This returns "datetime64[ns]" which seems good.

Finally, in the database, I have tried to change the data type from "Date" to "Datetime", but this doesn't solve the error.

Could anybody share some hints about how to resolve this error ?

Best Regards,

Edit on 25/04/2020 : Final solution

```
            df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start_date)
            df = df.reset_index()
            df.columns = ['price_date', 'open_price', 'high_price', 'low_price', 'close_price', 'adj_close_price', 'volume']
            df['data_vendor_id'] = YAHOO_VENDOR_ID
            df['ticker_id'] = ticker_index[ticker]
            df = df[['data_vendor_id','ticker_id','price_date', 'open_price', 'high_price', 'low_price', 'close_price', 'adj_close_price', 'volume']]
            df['price_date'] = df['price_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            print(df)
            cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO daily_price (data_vendor_id, ticker_id, price_date, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, adj_close_price, volume) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", df.to_numpy().tolist())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider converting your date time column to string representation of time and use `DataFrame.to_numpy()` instead of the `iterrows` approach:

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start_date)

# ADD NEW COLUMNS
df["data_vendor_id"] = YAHOO_VENDOR_ID
df["ticker_id"] = ticker_index[ticker]]

# CONVERT DATE TO STRING TIME
df["DATE"] = df["DATE"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


sql = '''INSERT INTO daily_price (data_vendor_id, ticker_id, price_date, 
                                  open_price, high_price, low_price, 
                                  close_price, adj_close_price, volume) 
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
      '''

# LIST
cursor.executemany(sql, df.to_numpy().tolist())
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Hello Parfait,
Thanks a lot for your answer.
I made a few "comfort" changes and it now works.
The "final solution" has been added to my initial post.
Best Regards,